# Can't call method from constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript

Calling private/public method from constructor in the same class gives me an error

> Uncaught TypeError: this.setEventHandler is not a function
>       at Object.Init (Init.ts:4)
>       at :3:16

```
export class Init {

constructor(private connectBtn: HTMLElement) {
    this.setEventHandler();
}
public setEventHandler() {
    this.connectBtn.onclick = (e) => {
        this.openConnectWindow();
    }
}
private openConnectWindow() {
    console.log("OPEN SESAME")
}
}
```

This is the compiled javascript

```
var Init = (function () {
function Init(connectBtn) {
    this.connectBtn = connectBtn;
    this.setEventHandler();
}
Init.prototype.setEventHandler = function () {
    var _this = this;
    this.connectBtn.onclick = function (e) {
        _this.openConnectWindow();
    };
};
Init.prototype.openConnectWindow = function () {
    console.log("OPEN SESAME");
};
return Init;
}());
```

Edit: This is for a library.

I tried putting var mylib = new MyLibraryName() but I only get "MyLibraryName is not a constructor".

I start the root object with webpack

```
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "lib"),
    filename: outputFile,
    library: libraryName,
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    umdNamedDefine: true
},
```

Comment: Show me how you create `Init` class instanses

Comment: Its going to be a library so i just type MyLibraryName.Init

Comment: var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-toggle')[0];
MyLibraryName.Init(ele)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the methods you are calling from other methods to this

```
export class Init {

constructor(private connectBtn: HTMLElement) {
    this.setEventHandler();
}

public setEventHandler = () => {
    this.connectBtn.onclick = (e) => {
        this.openConnectWindow();
    }
}

private openConnectWindow = () => {
    console.log("OPEN SESAME")
}
}
```

Comment: Could you tell us why is this necessary?

Comment: Yes, it works like charm, but why should I use this? It changes my syntax. Is there any way we can configure something to make it work on both ways?